# Scanner throwing null pointer when trying to get next

Tags: java

```
public class ScannerTest {

    protected Scanner scan;

    public ScannerTest(String s) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);

    }

    public void getone() {

        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            String temp = scan.next();
            temp = temp.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]", "");
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "(abcd) (defg) (w)";
        ScannerTest test = new ScannerTest(s);
        Scanner rando = new Scanner(s);
        System.out.println(rando.next());
        System.out.println(rando.hasNext());

        test.getone();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are re-declaring Scanner as a local variable in your constructor.  Since it has the name "scan" also, it's shadowing the field (class-level variable) also named scan.

To fix this, inside the constructor, just remove the Scanner part, and leave:

scan = new Scanner(s);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are victim of so called variable shadowing. 
With line

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
```

you are declaring a local variable scan instead of initialize your member scan inside a your ScannerTest class. Change the mentioned line to

```
scan = new Scanner(s);
```

and it will work as desired...

complete source code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SomeClass {

    protected Scanner scan;

    public SomeClass(String s) {
        scan = new Scanner(s);
    }

    public void getone() {

        if (scan.hasNext()){
            String temp = scan.next();
            temp = temp.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","");
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "(abcd) (defg) (w)";
        SomeClass test = new SomeClass(s);
        Scanner rando = new Scanner(s);
        System.out.println(rando.next());
        System.out.println(rando.hasNext());

        test.getone();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the weird formatting, this is my first post. The null pointer exception is being thrown in the getone() method. First at hasNext(), and if I remove that, at next().